# Facing problem while using Lucene's keyword analyzer

Tags: lucene, keyword, query-analyzer

Not able to use lucene's keyword analyzer properly,

```java
    String term = "new york";
    // id and location are the fields in which i want to search the "term"
    MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
                                       Version.LUCENE_30,
                                       {"id", "location"},
                                       new KeywordAnalyzer());
    Query query = queryParser.parse(term);
    System.out.println(query.toString());
```

OUTCOME: (id:new location:new) (id:york location:york)

**EXPECTED OUTCOME: (id:new york location:new york) (id:new york location:new york)**

Please help me identify what i am doing wrong here??

Comment: First thing, I'm curious this got compiled, because Eclipse tells me there's an error - I had to replace `{"id", "location"}` with `new String[]{"id", "location"}` (otherwise it is treated as two strings instead of an array). You compiled exactly this code, or replaced the parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. This is the way QueryParser works.
Since you are indexing your text as a single token with KeywordAnalyzer, you should use TermQuery. Since you have two fields to search, you can combine two TermQueries like:

```java
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", term)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD );
bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("location", term)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD );
string txtQuery = bq.ToString();
```

Comment: Only added [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints): `<!-- language: lang-java -->`

Comment: @L.B: Hey L.B Thanks for the response, Appreciate that.